# First time audio playing getting slow my Sprite Kit game?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I'm new with Sprite Kit, I have a short sound effect to play in a function. I have tried AVFoundation and SKAudioNode like below in that function. But I discovered It triggers some stuck for my SKActions. How Can I solve this playing problem. It looks waiting for completion or something different?

```
        let audioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "catch")
        audioNode.autoplayLooped = false
        self.addChild(audioNode)
        let playAction = SKAction.play()
        audioNode.run(playAction)
```

Comment: What kind of sound file you are trying to play? .mp3, .wav, .caf?

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm using .wav

Comment: Okay, so it is a short sound right? And do you have any other code aside from this? Did you try to isolate this and see if it works as described?

Comment: @Whirlwind Yes it's a short sound effect. I have tried simple main background thread but it didn't help me.

Comment: You mean you tried to play sound on a main thread? Your code should work by the way(on a real device). What kind of delay we are talking about? Second, two, more?

Comment: @Whirlwind Yes I checked it with 6S. Sound playing without delay. But my SKAction run stuck with 1.5 second delay when sound started play. (sound effect same length 1-1.5 sec.)

Comment: Have you tried `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("catch", waitForCompletion: false)`  instead of `SKAction.play()` ?

Comment: @Mina Thank you pretty smooth playing now :)

Comment: glad to hear that ;-)

Comment: i've added my solution which is worked for you as answer, so any one with the same problem can find the answer easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another action for playing sound file,
you can use
 `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("catch", waitForCompletion: false)`
instead of `SKAction.play()`.

There is a complete explanation of what *waitForCompletion* is doing in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417664-playsoundfilenamed)